# Error "skipping pax global extended headers" when installing devtools

Tags: r, devtools

I am trying to install the development version of `devtools` from github to R Open 3.5.1 using this code:

```
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("r-lib/devtools")
```

The first time I tried I got this output/error:

```
Downloading GitHub repo r-lib/devtools@master
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\JT\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8Cq1sJ\remotes215c357871af\r-lib-devtools-ab6c878/DESCRIPTION'
 1.  preparing 'devtools':
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
 2.  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
 3.  checking for empty or unneeded directories
 4.  building 'devtools_2.0.2.9000.tar.gz'

 5. installing *source* package 'devtools' ...
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
*** copying figures
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Warning: package 'usethis' was built under R version 3.5.3
 6. DONE (devtools)
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning messages:
1: In untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir) :
  skipping pax global extended headers
2: In untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir) :
  skipping pax global extended headers
```

When I run the same code a second time I get this message:

```
Warning messages:
1: In untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir) :
  skipping pax global extended headers
2: In untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir) :
  skipping pax global extended headers
```

My question is 3-fold:

1. What does "skipping pax global extended headers" mean? Is this a problem?
2. Did the installation of `devtools` work despite the warning messages? In my "Packages" list there is an entry for `devtools 2.0.2.9000, so I think it worked.
3. Is any of this related to either using R Open or the fact that R Open is not up-to-date with R (v3.5.1 vs v3.5.3)?

Thanks.

Comment: I have the very same problem. Did you get a solution?

Comment: I can't remember if I found a solution. I switched to regular R (and, I believe, the non-development version of devtools) and haven't had any problems.